# Travelling thorough schengen area while waiting for permesso

Tags: air-travel, schengen-visas, italy, spain, ryanair

I have a long-term type D visa for studying in Italy but it will expire on 31th Jan  and I have not received my permesso yet(I don't have any previous permesso)

I need to take a trip to Spain on 25th Jan and come back on 3th of Feb, 3 days after visa expiration date. I went to questura today to see if I can apply for a temporary permesso but couldn't get much information because I don't speak Italian.
If anyone can help me through this procedure or had the same situation before and know what would happen if I take this trip without temporary permesso, I really would appreciate to share it with me. 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

With your valid residence permit you can travel to Spain.

You should take your recieved application confirmation (**Poste Italiane SpA**) with you.

From the authorities there should be no problems when returning, but some airlines act as if they have more to say in the matter than they in reality have.

Printing out the *status* the progress of the residence permit just before leaving may also be helpful.

---

> Foreigners awaiting renewal of their residence permits **can leave and re-enter Italy** if they hold:
>
> - the receipt issued by Italian Post offices (**Poste Italiane SpA**) certifying the submission of the application for renewal of their residence permit or EC residence permit for long-term residents;
> - the expired residence permit;
> - their passport or other equivalent travel document .

---

> After submitting the application kit, the Post Office will give the applicant a **special receiptstating** that they have applied for the issue or renewal of their residence permit and a printout with their later appointment at the Police Headquarters. The applicant will find on the receipt a password and a user ID to check **the progress of their residence permit issue** [on the official national website of the State Police](http://questure.poliziadistato.it/servizio/stranieri/?mime=1&lang=english). (Please, enter the file number - 10 characters - or the registered mail code -12 characters - relating to the application for your residence permit).

---

**Sources**:

- [Requirements for immigrants leaving Italy temporarily | State Police](https://www.poliziadistato.it/articolo/10722-Requirements_for_immigrants_leaving_Italy_temporarily)
- [Issue / Renewal / Update of Residence Permits and Residence Cards](https://questure.poliziadistato.it/it/Arezzo/articolo/11045bc04cf3a33e7284773614)